# Destroy and redeploy a Private AWS API Gateway instance using the same API ID? OR another solution?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-api-gateway

I'm using Terraform to deploy private API Gateway instances, and typically when I make changes to the API, I need to actually destroy and redeploy it in order for the changes to go through and not to see some error in the resource policy.

(I deploy the APIs with swagger files and for some reason if I deploy changes to an existing API, it clears the resource policy to be an empty string, whether I'm changing the resource policy or not).

The issue is that every time I actually destroy and redeploy, the API ID changes and I need to change the code for every application consuming this ID. I thought of using a Route53 endpoint to put in front of the API so that applications can hit the endpoint instead of using the ID, but that is only supported for public APIs.

Any ideas on how I can redeploy these APIs without needing to change the ID on the consumer side?

Note: One idea is storing the API ID in Vault and having consumers call Vault to fetch the ID before calling the API, but I would rather look into AWS-contained solutions before going that route.

EDIT:

As a test, I ran a pipeline deploying the Terraform with no changes over the existing API. Here is the resulting plan:

```
An execution plan has been generated and is shown below.
Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  [33m~[0m update in-place
[0m
Terraform will perform the following actions:

[33m  [33m~[0m [33mmodule.api_gateway.aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api_var_name
[0m      description: "API description" => ""
      name:        "api_name" => "api_name"
      policy:      "{\"Version\":\"2012-10-17\",\"Statement\":[{\"Effect\":\"Allow\",\"Principal\":\"*\",\"Action\":\"execute-api:Invoke\",\"Resource\":\"arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:<REDACTED>:*\"},{\"Effect\":\"Deny\",\"Principal\":\"*\",\"Action\":\"execute-api:Invoke\",\"Resource\":\"arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:<REDACTED>:*\",\"Condition\":{\"StringNotEquals\":{\"aws:SourceVpce\":\"vpce-<REDACTED>\"}}}]}" => ""
[0m
[0m
[0m[1mPlan:[0m 0 to add, 1 to change, 0 to destroy.[0m
```

As you can see, Terraform only makes one change, and that is that it wipes the resource policy from the API. This also happens when I make a change to something else in the deployment unrelated to the API.

EDIT2:

My Terraform code for the API module:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "api_name" {
  name = "${var.api_gateway_name}${var.beta_id}"
  body = "${data.template_file.api_template.rendered}"

  endpoint_configuration {
    types = ["PRIVATE"]
  }
}

data "template_file" "api_template" {
  template = "${file("../source/apigateway-swagger.json")}"

  vars {
    session_init_arn = "${var.session_init_function_arn}"
    account_id       = "${var.account_id}"
    vpce_id          = "${var.vpce_id}"
    second_vpce_id   = "${var.second_vpce_id}"
    third_vpce_id    = "${var.third_vpce_id}"
    beta_id          = "${var.beta_id}"
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "api_name_deployment" {
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api_name.id}"
  stage_name  = "v1"
}
```

Policy part of swagger file:

```
  "x-amazon-apigateway-policy": {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:${account_id}:*"
      },
      {
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:${account_id}:*",
        "Condition": {
          "StringNotEquals": {
            "aws:SourceVpce": ["${vpce_id}", "${second_vpce_id}", "${third_vpce_id}"]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: I changed my infra to serverless because of this problem

Comment: @bodoroman do you mean serverless the framework? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Yes, I use Serverless framework. With serverless framework, you can redeploy API Gateway with same ID(arn).

Comment: This might be an XY problem. Could you show the change and the resulting plan that causes Terraform to replace your API gateway instead of updating in place? It could be that this is fixable directly.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I edited the post to show the terraform plan it gives me when deploying over an existing API.

Comment: None of that shows a forces new resource. Could you edit it to include the full relevant part of the plan but also more importantly provide the Terraform code as a [mcve] and show what change you are making, if any, that causes the full plan with the forces new resource to be shown?

Comment: The issue is not that Terraform creates a new resource when I don't want it to. The issue is that when I try to deploy changes to an existing API (and thus not changing the API ID), it causes problems, like clearing the resource policy. This means that I cannot make changes to existing API's, which forces me to destroy and redeploy each time I want to make a change, which in turn causes the API IDs to change. 

Let me know if we are on the same page.

Comment: I think the better question to ask here is "why is the provider planning to change the policy to be an empty string?", but to answer that question will require seeing the configuration of `aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api_var_name` and whatever its configuration refers to. Your current question amounts to "how I can I destroy a REST API without destroying it?", because creating a new API will always generate a new unique id, so I think it'd be better to find a way to avoid destroying it in the first place.

Comment: Still not sure if we're on the same page! I know it's a very specific problem. Nonetheless, I posted my Terraform code and the policy part of the Swagger file. Maybe someone will see the glaring problem that I don't!